# AAD B2B- SharePoint Online modern site- Suite bar inconsistencies

Tags: sharepoint, azure-ad-b2c

SharePoint guest users see different O365 suite bar branding than organizational AAD users. For SharePoint Online modern experience pages, suchs as Communication site homepage, My AAD B2B users are missing the app launcher, O365 client custom logo in center, and "Username" text in the header. Is this due to AAD licensing for B2B, or just a fluke? See screenshot. Thanks!

[image: B2B user on Modern communciation site vs backend modern experience vs 1st class licensed user on Modern page. random things appear, disappear and are formatted the name differently]

Can someone provide some either provide guidence on why these scenarios were selected along with thier resulting functionality (randomness) or provide a roadmap of if these are an issue and when they will be more consistent?

Comment: Well. For office 365 portal, you can only use the member account to login a specific tenant. I'm not 100% sure, it seems like that the guest user had login to the another tenant which is his original tenant. Also, try to refresh your browser,  some UI places may be the cache issue.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I am pointing out different that a B2B user has a different suite bar than a licensed user, and also how Modern vs Classic experience suite bar varies for liceneded users as well, 100% of the time (not some cache issue, etc.). This was built this way, and I want to know if it was intentional or not. When developing software UI's, customers really enjoy consitant UI's, and this one is not.